# Detect stop type using GTFS feed

Tags: sql, postgresql, gtfs

I have a GTFS feed and I am trying to detect stoptype (`bus`, `tram` or `multiple` in my case) using SQL. To do that, I have to get all routes on each stop and compare `route.route_type` field which contains information about route type (`0` - tram, `3` - bus).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT stop.stop_id, route.route_type from stop
INNER JOIN stop_time on stop_time.stop_id = stop.stop_id
INNER JOIN trip on trip.trip_id = stop_time.trip_id
INNER JOIN route on route.route_id = trip.route_id
GROUP BY stop.stop_id, route.route_type 
ORDER BY stop.stop_id, route.route_type
```

This query returns:

```
stop_id,route_type
1,0
1,3
2,0
3,3
```

Which means that stop_id = 1 has:

- bus routes,
- tram routes.

stop_id = 2 has only tram routes.

stop_id = 3 has only bus routes.

I would like to return:

```
stop_id,stop_type
1,multiple
2,tram
3,bus
```

Or maybe even easier would be just to modify only these stops which have bus and tram routes. So it would be something like this:

```
stop_id,stop_type
1,-1
2,0
3,3
```

How to achieve this result? I'm not sure but I think that I should count number of rows per stop_id and then somehow modify the result but I don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `COUNT` of DISTINCT `route_type` for each `stop_id` and if it is more than 1 then output `multiple`, otherwise use the `MAX` (or `MIN`, it doesn't matter since there is only one distinct value, but we must use an aggregation function to avoid violating group by rules) of `route_type` to set the `stop_type` to `bus` or `tram`:

```
SELECT stop.stop_id, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT route.route_type) > 1 THEN 'multiple'
            WHEN MAX(route.route_type) = 0 THEN 'tram'
            ELSE 'bus'
       END AS stop_type
FROM stop
INNER JOIN stop_time on stop_time.stop_id = stop.stop_id
INNER JOIN trip on trip.trip_id = stop_time.trip_id
INNER JOIN route on route.route_id = trip.route_id
GROUP BY stop.stop_id
ORDER BY stop.stop_id
```

Comment: Hmm, it returns `multiple` everywhere. However, when I modified `count(route.route_type)` to `count(distinct route.route_type)` it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @Marcin sorry about that - it wasn't clear from the data in your question that there could be multiple similar values. I'm glad you figured it out. I've updated the answer for future reference.